# Can't detect IE

Tags: internet-explorer, web, detect

I'm currently revamping a website for a local bank. Most of their customers are working with IE. I've used standards I thought were compatible with IE7 but it's absolutely shredding it apart. Surprisingly it looks a touch better in IE6. I've been trying to run a script to detect this. Many of which I have found on here.

i.e.

```
if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version=="6.0") alert("Please update your version of IE");
```

and

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
```

Content for IE 6

```
<![if !IE 6]>
```

Content not for IE

and I've also tried some style switching

```
 <!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 7)]>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ie6-7.css">
 <![endif]-->
```

•So I'm wondering if anyone can lend some help. Just assume there's no issues with my code. I would post it but it's for a bank and I don't want to cause any issues.

p.s.- any reason why the, border="0" fix for the ugly borders around images in IE is deprecated element? They want the code to validate and look nice in IE, is this at all posible?

Comment: Use CSS instead: `style="border: 0;"`. Or put this rule in a stylesheet, it will remove the border from all linked images (all `img`s that are inside an `a`): `a img{ border: 0; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use soemthing like [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) for browser detection.

The better solution, however, would be to detect the (breaking) features and insert polyfills in case they are not supported. A great resource for this is [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), which also provides quite a list of [polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills).

Answer (score 0):

conditional stylesheets are completely fine and the preferred way to style for IE. You can use proprietary elements and hide it from the other browsers. Everything okay with that.

border="0" is deprecated like many other attributes to encourage the user to style elements via css and not those ugly inline elements (separate style and content).

And your browserswitch via $.browser (i assume it's jQuery?) is okay, too.

This should be of great help for you: [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#) and [MS compat table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Everything should be save and sound, if you go that way.